# (Node/Express) Express-sitemap generating incorrect sitemap

Tags: xml, node.js, express, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm attempting to generate a sitemap for my website using the express-sitemap middleware.  My code is as follows:

```
var sitemap = require('express-sitemap')();
//...
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})
//...
posts = [
  post2 = {
    "url":
    "wild-birds",
  },    
  post1 = {
    "url":
    "top-dogs-cats",
  }
]

app.get('/:leg', function(req, res, next) {
    for (i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
        if (req.params.leg == posts[i].url) {
            res.render('post', { posts2:posts[i] });
        }
    }
//The above code checks to see which blog post was requested by
//the user, and responds by rendering the associated HTML (with some
//additional information I chose to exclude from this post)
})

console.log(sitemap.generate(app))
```

---

This outputs:

```
{ '/': [ 'get' ],
  '/:leg': [ 'get' ] }
```

---

When it should be outputting:

```
{ '/': [ 'get' ],
  '/wild-birds': [ 'get' ],
  '/top-dogs-cats': [ 'get' ]
 }
```

---

How should I go about fixing this sitemap generator? Additionally, how would you suggest serving the corrected sitemap.xml to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[express-sitemap](https://github.com/hex7c0/express-sitemap/blob/master/index.js) iterates over all registered routes to generate the sitemap. Internally it calls: `app._router.stack` and then filters all routes.

You should register your posts explicitly as routes instead of using a parameter. Do this instead:

```
posts.forEach(function(post) {
  app.get('/' + post.url, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('post', {
      posts2: post
    });
    // your logic...
  });
});
```

Then calling `console.log(sitemap.generate(app))` returns what you'd expect:

```
{ '/': [ 'get' ],
  '/wild-birds': [ 'get' ],
  '/top-dogs-cats': [ 'get' ] }
```